# Can I Mass Re-link Files in InDesign? Same Name, Just New Extension?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've got a document that has several dozen photos that I've kept in *.psd* until i was done editing. Now I've shot myself in the foot as I'd like to re-link all of these to the *.tif* version. (Easy Photoshop batch). The file names would remain the same, just the extension changes.

Is there a way to do this without having to manually re-link each photo? I'm thinking even a script maybe?

Thanks for your time. -Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution!

In the Links panel (Window > Links) select your images and from the menu in the top right corner (the 4 lines) select Relink File Extension.